# Data is not coming in text view getting sqlite exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new in android if this question is repeating sorry for that.
My issue is i have one ProjectManagerfargment there i have one spinner which belongs to employeefragment and some textview where i am setting the data from databasehandler method so, i am selecting the spinner fields and based on that i am setting the value in textview but i am getting like the column is not present which is date column. Thank you, please anybody suggest me right thing.

This is my Database initialization, table creation and method code

```
private static final String KEY_TASKID1 = "idtask1";
private static final String KEY_TASKNAME1 = "taskname1";
private static final String KEY_TASKEID1 = "taskeid1";
private static final String KEY_TASKPID1 = "taskpid1";
public static final String KEY_STARTDATE1 = "startdate";
public static final String KEY_ENDDATE1 = "enddate1";

String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "("
            + KEY_TASKID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TASKNAME1 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TASKEID1 + " TEXT," + KEY_TASKPID1 + " TEXT," + KEY_STARTDATE1 + "TEXT," + KEY_ENDDATE1 +"TEXT"+ ")";

public Task getProjectmanagerName(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Task task = new Task();
    String query ="SELECT  " + KEY_TASKNAME1 +", " +KEY_TASKPID1 +","+ KEY_STARTDATE1 +","+ KEY_ENDDATE1 +" FROM " + TABLE_TASKS+ " WHERE " + KEY_TASKEID1 + "=" + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            task.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            task.setPid(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setStartdate(cursor.getString(2));
            task.setEnddate(cursor.getString(3));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return task;

}
```

This is my fragment class code

```
m_name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectedManager =Integer.toString(((Employee)con.get(position)).getID());
            Log.i("projectid",selectedManager);
            task=db.getProjectmanagerName(selectedManager);
             manager.setText(task.getName());
             project.setText(task.getPid());
             start.setText(task.getStartdate());
             end.setText(task.getEnddate());
        }
```

This one from Log cat

```
01-10 05:58:37.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1839): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: startdate (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  taskname1, taskpid1,startdate,enddate FROM Task WHERE taskeid1=1
```

Comment: please see i updated.

Comment: `startdate` and `enddate` column not available in table

Comment: Please uninstall the app and try again ...

Comment: For future reference, you can use the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) function to see if your question already has an answer out there. Also, when you write your question, you get suggestions of possibly relevant questions.

Comment: Yeah @Reti43 i 'll do that thank for advice.

Comment: the log cat says it all, no such column: startdate (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  taskname1, taskpid1,startdate,enddate FROM Task WHERE taskeid1=1

the sqlite is receiving the column name as startdate when you define it as startdate1, try enclosing your column names with `` in the sql statement

Comment: Hi, @Reti43 i searched as much i can but i was not able to find right thing so that i think i should ask.

Comment: Of course. I'm not being judgemental, just giving friendly advice based on your opening line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some spaces here:

```
KEY_STARTDATE1 + "TEXT," + KEY_ENDDATE1 +"TEXT"+ ")";
```

Change to

```
KEY_STARTDATE1 + " TEXT," + KEY_ENDDATE1 +" TEXT"+ ")";
```

and uninstall your app so the database gets recreated.

Comment: Hi, @laalto sorry for being late its all about emulator i am not using device the database error has been resolved however date is not associated with textview ref.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public static final String KEY_STARTDATE1 = "startdate1";
```

to

```
public static final String KEY_STARTDATE1 = "startdate";
```

if the error remains same, update the database version and runagain.

Comment: i just changed but error is same that was a my mistake i posted old error that time i did same which u suggest me to do.

Comment: Update your database version and try it. Make sure you have dropped the table and recreated it on your upgrade.

Comment: i did that there were problem with table creation small thing

Comment: now database is ok but data is not attaching to the textview